# Copying my Ubuntu vmware workstation virtual machine (desktop) to my laptop as a physical machine - How to get it boot

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 (64-bit) as a virtual machine (vmware workstation) on my desktop PC with Windows 10 Education (64-bit) being the host. With my desktop PC having enough horsepower, I can run Ubuntu just like an other app. There are no compatibility issues with Windows and vmware Workstation helping out, so I am very content with this setting.

My problem is that I have to program in OCaml for the time being and running OCaml under Windows is really no fun. The compiler has been ported to Windows (with a few adjustment and the removal of make files) by some company but there isn´t any real documentation, yet. And with cygwin there is the GPL issue I try to avoid whenever possible.

Running a virtual machine on my Laptop is possible and no problem for occasional uses but it drains the battery and can get sometimes slow.

So I created a second partition on my Laptop and installed EsayBCD on Windows 10.

While doing that, I had the idea of copying the content of my virtual machine to an external drive and from that internal drive to the newly created partition. This way I would save myself a lot of tweaking, configuring, installing (Ubuntu´s software center´s software is far too outdated and I need quite a bit of extra software). But I haven´t tried this yet, guessing that this wouldn´t just work.

I know that while I can copy Windows from one partition to an other, I cannot do so to an other PC. Googleing, I found out that this is also true for Ubuntu.

So is there a way to achieve this (without rewriting the whole OS :) )? Both PCs use an Intel core processor (though not the same one).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dpkg --get-selections > software.txt` to save a list of all packages you have installed, install Ubuntu to the laptop, copy just that file over, and run `dpkg --set-selections < software.txt` to reinstall all of the same applications on the new system.  This is probably the easiest way.

If you really want to copy the whole system as is, then you need to copy all of the files over, then manually install grub.  Boot the install cd, mount the new partition, chroot into it, and reinstall grub to make it boot:

```
sudo -s
mount -t ext4 /dev/sdaX /mnt
for f in proc sys dev dev/pts run; do mount --bind /$f /mnt/$f ; done
chroot /mnt
dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

Select /dev/sda for where to install grub to and update the UUIDs in /etc/fstab ( you can see the current UUIDs with `lsblk` ) and you should be able to reboot from the hard drive now.

Comment: Yes, I really want to copy the entire OS. It´s not so much about installing the same set of programs but about having to tweak them and Ubuntu (and Ubuntu needs a lot of tweaking in my opinion). So thanks. I am going to try it later. This seems far easier than I thought it would be. I hope it will work.

Comment: @Willi, ahh, I forgot the part about updating the UUIDs in /etc/fstab that cas included in his answer ( I usually use LVM names instead of UUIDs ).

Comment: On my laptop sadaX = sada3. That's where I want grub to be installed in order to keep Windows boot loader in charge and intact. When I enter dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc and try to install grub, I get following error message:

Comment: root@ubuntu:/# dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-18-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-17-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-17-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin

Comment: logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory

Comment: logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory

Comment: /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
done

Comment: Oops, I forgot about /run... that list of bind mounts keeps getting longer each release.  I don't think those warnings stopped it from working though.

Comment: With the help of run, grub has been installed successfully. The problem is that Ubuntu won´t boot successfully. ntpdate[855]: name server cannot be used: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)                dhclient[752]: Error getting hardware address for "eno1677773b": No such device          systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dServer\x2d/x2dvg\x2dswap_1.device

Comment: @Willi, that is saying it can't find your swap partition.. system should still boot without it.

Comment: It allows me to boot into command-line root. "Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs. "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to try again to boot into default mode. Give root password for mantainance (or press Control-D to continue):" Pressing Control-D results into "Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1)"

Comment: I think I have to figure out how to remove the swap partition using the command line.

Comment: I have used swapoff -a. I still get "No such device systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dServer\x2d/x2dvg\x2dswap_1.device" "System[1] Dependency failed for dev/mapper/ubuntu--Server--vg-swap_1"

Comment: @Willi, `swapoff` does not remove a partition, it just tells the kernel to stop using it for now.  Your /etc/fstab file lists what partitions, including swap, should be mounted during boot.  Either remove the swap entry from there, or update it to point to the UUID of the new swap partition.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike windows, linux systems can easily be cloned from one machine or disk to another as just a file copy.  The only thing you have to be careful about is making sure `grub` is properly installed and has a working grub.cfg

If you can mount the extra partition in your VM, you should just be able to rsync your VM's files over to the new partition.  You can run the rsync as many times as you like until you are ready to finish the final setup.

If the VM is on your desktop PC and the partition is on your laptop, just boot a rescue CD/USB stick on the laptop, get networking and sshd up and running, format and mount the partition, and then rsync via ssh from the running VM to the laptop's partition.

To finalise the clone, you'll need a rescue CD or USB stick.  gparted or clonezilla or systemrescuecd will do.

- install `os-prober` if it isn't already installed.  this is so grub will be able to find your windows partition and add it to the grub boot menu.
- Boot the rescue USB or CD.
- get to a root shell
- mount the target partition as, say, /target
- bind-mount /sys, /proc, and /dev under /target

`for i in proc dev sys ; do mount -o bind /$i /target/$i ; done`

- chroot /target
- edit `/etc/fstab` so that it refers to your new partition.  You may need to run `blkid` to get the UUID of the partition if you are mounting by UUID=
- run `update-grub`
- run `grub-install /dev/sdX` where /dev/sdX is the device name of your boot drive (probably /dev/sda`)
- `exit` from the chroot
- unmount the bind mounts and /target

`for i in proc dev sys / ; do umount /target/$i ; done`

- reboot.
- you should now get a grub menu offering you a choice of your linux distro or windows.

Astute readers will notice that this is basically identical to the procedure for cloning any other system or for repairing a broken grub install.